# Red5/Tomcat "403 forbidden" error on a certain directory

Tags: flash, tomcat, red5, http-status-code-403

Windows 7 local environment.

My setup is this:

`Red5/webapps/app/streams/vid.flv`

I need to access the video. I'm trying to play the file through JW player, but it gives a `not found or access denied` error

I typed in the path, that the JW player displays, in a browser, which is `localhost:5080/app/streams/vid.flv` and it gives me a `http 403` error.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

---

More information:

I can go to `http://localhost:5080/webapp/`
And see the directory listing, which has `streams` and `temp` in it.

I can go into `temp`, and get another directory listing.

I can't, however, go into `streams`, because when I try, it gives me a `403`

The directory listing also gives me the Tomcat version information, which is`Apache Tomcat/6.0.26`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far that I know Red5 doesn't support `http streaming`. As you are using  JW Player you can play it using `rtmp protocol`

Folow [this tutorial](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming/) to setup the JW Player to play the video using `rtmp`.

**Update for "403 forbidden"**

By default the web.xml inside the red5 app is configured to forbid the access to the `streams folder`. Remove the piece of code below to access it:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Forbidden</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/streams/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
```

But remember, by accessing the `.flv` file using the direct url path it will download the file but wont stream it.

Comment: According to that tutorial, my JW player should be set up correctly to retrieve the file, but it still can't play it, nor can I access the local file with a web browser